# is_page() function not displaying content to specific page ID's

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to simply just output some HTML onto these 3 specific page-ids that I am referring too in the code below. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this php isn't working? (its at the bottom of my functions.php file in the child theme.

```html
 if( is_page('96') || is_page('98') || is_page('61') ) { ?> 
    <div class="test"><h2>test content</h2></div>
 <?php }
```

Any help would be appreciated as to why this 'test content' is not appearing on these pages.
Thanks!

Comment: "isn't working" is a little bit generical. Can you explain more? What did you expect?

Comment: I was expecting it to output this html onto these specified wordpress page ID's. But nothing is being added to the page.

Comment: you need to put the code in page.php or index.php (whichever is used to display those pages), not in functions.php

Comment: Ive added it into the single.php file but now as I try to open the page it is completely white with nothing being displayed at all. Appreciate the help btw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code that will work properly.

```
if( is_page(96) || is_page(98) || is_page(61) ) : ?> 
    <div class="test"><h2>test content</h2></div>
 <?php endif;
```

=====================  or  ==========================

```
$id = get_the_ID();
if( ($id == 96) || ($id == 98) || ($id == 61) ) : ?> 
        <div class="test"><h2>test content</h2></div>
     <?php endif;
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Looks like I had a few syntax errors! Thank you for the help! Much appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`get_the_ID();` or `$post->ID;`. you will get the ID of the current post of the loop

like this

```
$ids = [96, 78];
if(in_array(get_the_ID(), $ids)) echo '<div class="test"><h2>test content</h2></div>';
```

Please take a look at the docs :

- [For is_page function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/)
- [To get the ID from the loop](http://%20https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/)

Comment: Hi, thankyou for trying to help. You have a syntax error missing out a closing ')' however even when I've added this in it is still not displaying on the pages.

Comment: What do you have by using get_the_ID ?

Comment: $ids = [96, 98, 61];
if(in_array(get_the_ID(), $ids)) echo '<div class="test"><h2>test content</h2></div>'; however continues to not output the div onto the 3 page ID's

Comment: Apologies Im an absolute beginner when it comes to php!

Comment: Did you add <?php at the begining of your code ?

Comment: Yes it is in the bottom of my functions.php file in the child theme.

Comment: past my code in the **single.php**, won't work in **functions.php** cause it's not in the loop

Comment: Ive added it into the single.php file but now as I try to open the page it is completely white with nothing being displayed at all. Appreciate the help btw!

Comment: Thanks for adding that answer. When you're contributing, please make sure to quote external documentation rather than link out to it as those links could break over time.

Comment: Dan have you enable error display ? @BlakeMorgan thanks to notice this, i'll change it